# how to show jpg images using cr 10.5 with visual studio 2008

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports-2008

I'm using vs 2008 and crystal report version 10.5 (i saved images path in sql database)

I want to put dynamic image 
how can I do 
please help me.

Comment: [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 0):

You can Ref [this](http://dotnetbd.wordpress.com/2008/06/20/display-dynamic-image-in-crystal-report-net/)
 OR follow the steps

*–> When file path store in database and need to show image in details section of crystal report*

If you have imagepath that store in your database, Crystal Report .NET in Visual Studio 2003/2005 cannot display image file dynamically unless you use dynamic image location feature in Crystal Report XI.

But don’t worry, it can display with some work around for this.

1. You must have imagepath in your database.
2. Create new Dataset/XML Schema (xsd) to use as resource data in creating report. Add an additional field that is not in the table and which is of type base64Binary :
3. When designing a report drag and drop the “image_stream” field in the region where you want it to appear.
4. Add the following method in you code:

   private void AddImageColumn(DataTable objDataTable, string strFieldName)
   {
   try
   {
   DataColumn objDataColumn = new DataColumn(strFieldName, Type.GetType(“System.Byte[]“));
   objDataTable.Columns.Add(objDataColumn);
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   Response.Write(“”+ex.Message+””);
   }
   }
5. And this one to load the image:

   private void LoadImage(DataRow objDataRow, string strImageField, string FilePath)
   {
   try
   {
   FileStream fs = new FileStream(FilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read);
   byte[] Image = new byte[fs.Length];
   fs.Read(Image, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
   fs.Close();
   objDataRow[strImageField] = Image;
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
   Response.Write(“”+ex.Message+””);
   }
   }
6. Before assigning the dataset to the “SetDataSource” of your report, add the following code:

   AddImageColumn(ds.Tables[0], “image_stream”);
   for (int index=0; index < ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count; index++)
   {
   if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["image_path"].ToString() != “”)
   {
   if(File.Exists(this.Server.MapPath(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["image_path"].ToString())))
   {
   LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], “image_stream”, ds.Tables[0].Rows[index]["image_path"].ToString());
   }
   else
   {
   LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], “image_stream”, “C:\NoImage.jpg”);
   }
   }
   else
   {
   LoadImage(ds.Tables[0].Rows[index], “image_stream”, “C:\NoImage.jpg”);
   }
   }
7. And finally to display report in crystal report viewer

   crDoc.SetDatabaseLogon(UserID, Password, Server, Database);
   crDoc.SetDataSource(ds.Tables[0]);
   CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = crDoc;

Non tested.

Comment: Thank You very much. I can not do it. Please tell me what  i do ?

Answer (score 0):

It is actually easy, follow this stapes:

1. unless you're already using OLE, create new connection of database field of Form crystareport1
2. select OLE DB(ADO)
3. add table where image is stored.
4. provide database information required by the system
5. now you have added a table into database Fields.
6. just drag and drop image into section3 area.
7. link this as you link simple for show other record.

I have tested it in my  project